# How I can download this directory?

Tags: linux, unix, wget

Is it possible to download this entire directory with wget? How I can do that?
This is the directory with the files that I want to download: `http://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show/trunk/fighterfish/sample`

Comment: Did you try `wget --help` or reading its documentation ?

Comment: Why wget? Why not `svn co https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/trunk/fighterfish/sample/`?

Comment: @Banthar, you should make your comment an answer. Barring any specific reason OP wants to use wget, a svn checkout would be the most appropriate way to get code from a repository.

Answer (score 3):

Referance the [GNU Wget Manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/wget/wget_31.html), it has everything you'll need to know about using wget.

This may not answer your question, but this will create a 5 level deep mirror of the directory you give it.

"Create a five levels deep mirror image of the GNU web site, with the same directory structure the original has, with only one try per document, saving the log of the activities to `gnulog':

```
wget -r http://www.gnu.org/ -o gnulog
```

"

Answer (score 3):

If you have no option other than wget, you could use `wget -m http://java.net/projects/glassfish/sources/svn/show/trunk/fighterfish/sample`, otherwise, like it had been mentioned use an SVN client and use this url: `https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn`.

If you want to use the command-line: `svn co https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn`